# Migrated Magento to new server. Cant get emails to send to customer

Tags: email, magento-community, migration, send-mail

A little help please.

We've migrated our Magento (1.7) to a new server.  Everything is working fine except the email confirmation.  We're receiving orders, payments, etc.  But the emails are not sending to the customer.  We receive the order confirmation email fine but not the customer, nor the shipping, credit memo, etc.

I'm sure its probably just a little something we have to change but unsure where.  Have checked here, google.  have checked on magento for the email settings, server & office 365.  All of our magento & server settings appear to be the same (still have the other one to access able but disabled).  Office 365 only points to our domain.  The only difference i can think of is the new ip but nothing seems to be needing it as it all searches for the domain.  Last emails received from magento to customers was when it was still on the old server.

I've gone around in circles now & seem to be rechecking things several times again & again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Oops, i should supply some more helpful info.  emails are setup as per original install (Zend ??, the office365 bit above is incorrect, i believe), MySQL is 5.1.73, dedicated server with fasthosts, migration was done via migration tool in plesk, only thing that is different from what i can tell is the ip (which has been transfered onto the domain name) but everything is uses the domain name.  Is there a file hidden in the depths that need changing??  I apologies for some of the vagueness, recently took on this site & don't have all of the info or knowledge yet!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the few details you have posted it could be simply a DNS propagation issue as it can take up to 48 hours for site migrations to show everywhere but if it's only the Magento store that has moved and not your mailserver then this is unlikely.

I usually install and configure the ebizmarts MageMonkey Official MailChimp and Mandrill Extension for Magento clients and even with the free Mandrill account level you will have a robust third party system to send Magento transactional emails but crucially Mandrill provides a great way of checking your transactional email history so you can spot any issues like this with deliverbility.

Comment: Yeah, its only the store that had moved ip.  Have checked the config>sales emails, Config>system>mail sending options.  Checked Cron is working,  Nothings any different. Really odd.  Reluctant to install another extension onto something that has only moved.  Thanks for the advise though, appreciated.

Comment: Something else we just notice.  Trying to install an extension (smtp), we now don't have access to connect.  Timeout 504 but with max_excute set at 500!!